# SwiftUI progress circle with interval timer

Tags: ios, swift, timer, swiftui, intervals

I'm trying to create a component where I have multiple time intervals that control a circle progress indicator.  When an interval completes, I want to immediately start the next interval and kick off the next progress animation.

So far, the only way I can do it is to have a 1 second delay from one interval ending to the next one starting.

Is anyone able to point me in the direction of how I might be able to achieve this?  I'm pretty new to Swift and SwiftUI so maybe I have taken completely the wrong approach here and there is a better way to do this?

```
struct CircleProgress: View {
  let timer = Timer.publish(every: 1.0, on: .current, in: .common)
  
  let timeDurations = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0]

  @State var timeDuration = 0.0
  @State var durationIndex = 0
  @State var progress = 0.0
  @State var isFinished = false

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      ZStack {
        Circle()
          .stroke(lineWidth: 32)
          .opacity(0.25)
          .rotationEffect(.degrees(90))
          .padding()
        
        VStack {
          Text("Progress: \(progress)")
          if self.isFinished {
            Text("Finished")
          }
        }
        
        Circle()
          .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(min(progress, 1.0)))
          .stroke(style: StrokeStyle(lineWidth: 32, lineCap: .round, lineJoin: .round))
          .foregroundColor(getStrokeColor())
          .rotationEffect(.degrees(-90))
          .padding()
          .onReceive(timer) { _ in
            if progress < 1 {
              withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 1.0)) {
                incrementProgress()
              }
            } else {
              progress = 0
              incrementDurationIndex()
            }
          }
      }.padding()
      Button(action: { startTimer() }) { Text("Start") }
      Spacer()
    }
  }
  
  func startTimer() {
    timeDuration = timeDurations[durationIndex]
    var _ = timer.connect()
  }
  
  func incrementDurationIndex() {
    durationIndex += 1
    if durationIndex < timeDurations.count {
      timeDuration = timeDurations[durationIndex]
    } else {
      setFinished()
      cancelTimer()
    }
  }
  
  func stopTimer() {
    timer.connect().cancel()
  }
  
  func setFinished() {
    isFinished = true
  }
  
  func incrementProgress() {
    progress += 1 / timeDuration
  }
  
  func cancelTimer() {
    timer.connect().cancel()
  }
  
  private func getStrokeColor() -> Color {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: Your challenge is that you need to increment to the next duration when then animation is complete, not when the timer next ticks, but SwiftUI doesn't have an in-built "animation complete" function - You can add this functionality - https://www.avanderlee.com/swiftui/withanimation-completion-callback/ but it isn't straight-forward.  A simpler "fix" is to just have your timer tick ever 0.1 of a second and change the animation duration and progress increment accordingly.  Now the next progress starts 0.1 of a second after the previous; still a delay but barely noticeable.